# The import com.apple.dnssd cannot be resolved. Eclipse, Win32

Tags: java, eclipse, import, bonjour, dns-sd

I have a problem: suddenly (exactly like that) my Eclipse IDE had lost the com.apple.dnssd library. "Yesterday" I was developing an app, "today" it brings me that error from the title.
What is interesting, I can still import:

```
com.apple.*;
com.apple.jdirect.*;
com.apple.mrj.*;
com.apple.mrj.macos.*;
com.apple.mrj.macos.carbon.*;
```

So the only dnssd is missing.

I have the Bonjour API installed correctly, I've installed the 2.0.4 version from the apple dev and was working with it. I have the dns_sd.jar both in the Bonjour directory and in the jre7. I tried to reinstall Bonjour from SDK. The same thing. 
I just cant get what went wrong. Any ideas?

--- EDIT ---

When Eclipse reads included libraries in the project it reads ALL the libs from %jre%\lib, %jre%\lib\ext, except this only file: dns_sd.jar. When I create a new project it also includes exactly all the files needed except this... How can this be?? What is wrong with that? It was all OK a couple of days ago?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something went wrong in .metadata configs of the Workspace folder. I deleted this .metadata folder, reimported all projects back in IDE and my problem was solved. Hope this will help others.